# Access azure billing API

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-api-management

I would like to create a dashboard with graphs about costs of my azure resources (as detailed as possible). Meaning, a list of monthly invoices is not enough (but I would already be very happy if I a could achieve that!!)

Anyway, the first thing I noticed is that if you find an example the endpoint urls look like this

```
 https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourcegroups?api-version=2016-09-01
```

Check the end of the url `2016-09-01`, doesn't look very up2date. [This](https://medium.com/@sambowenhughes/getting-started-with-the-microsoft-azure-billing-apis-aa27af11c1d0)  medium post was the best article I could find, but it also uses these urls. 
Furthermore, I was not able to follow the steps described, first it uses postman to retrieve an `access_token` (not very useful for me because I need it automated) and second, somewhere in the middle an access_token is retrieved but never used.

So, I found a npm packages like `[azure-arm-billing][2]` from which I was able to write the following program (mostly copy-paste):

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const BillingManagement = require('azure-arm-billing')

const clientId = process.env['CLIENT_ID'];
const secret = process.env['APPLICATION_SECRET'];
const domain = process.env['DOMAIN']; 
const subscriptionId = process.env['AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'];

// Retrieve access_token
const app = new msRestAzure.ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret);
app.getToken((err, token) => {
    console.log(token.accessToken);
});

// =======
msRestAzure
  .interactiveLogin( { domain }) // The argument here is nowhere documented
  .then(credentials => {
      console.log(credentials);
      let client = new BillingManagement(credentials, subscriptionId);
      return client.invoices.list();
  })
  .then(invoices => {
      console.log('List of invoices:');
      console.dir(invoices, { depth: null, colors: true });
  });
```

Running this shows a nice access_token and invoices

```
...
List of invoices:
[
  {
    id: '/subscriptions/../providers/Microsoft.Billing/invoices/....',
    name: '...',
    type: 'Microsoft.Billing/invoices',
    invoicePeriodStartDate: 2019-08-25T00:00:00.000Z,
    invoicePeriodEndDate: 2019-09-24T00:00:00.000Z,
    billingPeriodIds: [
      '/subscriptions/.../pr..s/Micro..ing/bill..ods/201910-1'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '/subscriptions/9ea...3d/providers/Microsoft.Billing/invoices/201909-...',
    name: '....',
    type: 'Microsoft.Billing/invoices',
    invoicePeriodStartDate: 2019-07-25T00:00:00.000Z,
    invoicePeriodEndDate: 2019-08-24T00:00:00.000Z,
    billingPeriodIds: [
      '/subscriptions/..../providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201909-1...'
    ]
  }
]
```

Although I have my invoices, there are no numbers. And I would like to retrieve costs for every resources.

So the documentation seems to be outdated up to not existing for what I want (as it seems). My question is if someone was able to retrieve information like this? I would really like to know how!!

**UPDATE**
It seems to be a permission issue. So, below I share some screenshots showing what I have right now. Maybe from these it is clear what I miss or have setup incorrectly. So first, here is my latest nodejs app:

```
const msRestAzure = require("ms-rest-azure");
const ConsumptionManagementClient = require("azure-arm-consumption");

const clientId = '76d79....';          // App registration ID
const secret = '****...';              // App registration secret
const domain =  'dc36...';             // tenantId
const subscriptionId = '9ea2d...';     // subscription ID

const AzureServiceClient = msRestAzure.AzureServiceClient;

//an example to list resource groups in a subscription
msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain).then((creds) => {
    const client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
    const expand = '';
    const filter = '';
    const skiptoken = '';
    const top = 1000;
    const apply = '';
    return client.usageDetails.list(expand, filter, skiptoken, top, apply).then(result => {
    console.log('The result is:', result);
  });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred:');
  console.dir(err, { depth: null, colors: true });
});
```

Which outputs a statusCode `401`

```
Error: Unauthorized. Request ID: e6b127...
...
```

So, I have in AD an App registration

[image]

Its API permissions are

[image]

Finally, I have just one subscription

[image]

With the following IAM settings

[image]

Any suspicious?

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve costs for all resources based on an invoice?

Comment: If that's the only way, its ok. But right now, I'm looking for just costs of resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for resource costs, I would suggest that you take a look at [`Consumption API - List Usage Details`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list). That will give you the consumption for all the resources.

You will need to install `azure-arm-consumption` package.

Here's the sample code:

```
const msRestAzure = require("ms-rest-azure");
const ConsumptionManagementClient = require("azure-arm-consumption");
msRestAzure.interactiveLogin().then((creds) => {
    const subscriptionId = "<your subscription id>";
    const client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(creds, subscriptionId);
    const expand = "";
    const filter = "";
    const skiptoken = "";
    const top = 1000;
    const apply = "";
    return client.usageDetails.list(expand, filter, skiptoken, top, apply).then((result) => {
      console.log("The result is:");
      console.log(result);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred:');
  console.dir(err, {depth: null, colors: true});
});
```

This is taken from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/consumptionManagement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links. But whatever I do I still get a 401: `Error: The access token is from the wrong issuer.....` and when I t use `loginWithServicePrincipalSecret` I get a 401 as well with the messahe: `Error: Unauthorized. Request ID: 6935...` Do you know how to fix this or maybe a link? –

Comment: I just tried it with a `Service Principal` and I was able to get the data. Please check for two things: 1) For this Service Principal, please ensure that you have `Azure Service Management` permission under `API permissions` section and 2) This Service Principal has been assigned appropriate RBAC role (Reader should be fine) at the Subscription level.

Comment: tried to fix the permission, without success so far. I updated the my post with a couple of screenshots. Maybe you could have a look. I must be doing something stupid!

Comment: Your role seems incorrect. Can you try by granting "Reader" role (in the 3rd screenshot)?

Comment: That did the trick, I managed to connect that role to my service principal and the `401` is gone, this really makes my day :) Next challenge now however, is that it always returns an empty array. I just created a K8S cluster and App Service, so I expect to see something right? What exactly should I get with this request? What I would like to see are the cost in (near) realtime of my resources

Comment: That would depend on how the resources are metered and consumption is reported. With the Billing API (old one, now deprecated) the delay was about a day.

Comment: It seems to work now, I can confirm that the delay is a day. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-usage-rate-card-overview) it is stated: `Hourly or Daily Aggregations - Callers can specify whether they want their Azure usage data in hourly buckets or daily buckets. The default is daily.` Any idea where this can be changed?